# distinct records based on a field is not listing after grouping based on another field in rails4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, associations

I have a query to list unique records based on project_parent_id field. The records should be listed based on the last updated_at time. Means, only one record can appear for a day, for one project_parent_id.

The used query is:

```
Project.unscoped.group("updated_at,project_parent_id,id").select("distinct project_parent_id,id,updated_at").order(updated_at: :desc).where('Date(projects.updated_at)>=? and Date(projects.updated_at)<=? and projects.last_modified_by=? and projects.project_parent_id is not ?', start_date, end_date, user_id,nil)
```

**The result obtained is:**

Project:0x0000000bd2a568 id: 2973, updated_at: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 10:03:27 UTC +00:00, project_parent_id: 2966,

Project:0x0000000bd2a400 id: 2972, updated_at: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 09:45:03 UTC +00:00, project_parent_id: 2964,

Project:0x0000000bd2a298 id: 2971, updated_at: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 09:44:30 UTC +00:00, project_parent_id: 2966

But, the last record not expecting in the result. The last record and first record has the same project_parent_id: 2966. Only the first two records are enough.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting distinct combinations of '`project_parent_id,id,updated_at`'. The last record is returned because the `project_parent_id` is different than the one in the first record. As you said

> Means, only one record can appear for a day, for one
>   project_parent_id.

So there is no mistake in your result set.

Comment: last record and first record has same `project_parent_id: 2966`

Comment: **Project:0x0000000bd2a568 id: 2973**, updated_at: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 10:03:27 UTC +00:00, project_parent_id: 2966
                                      Project:0x0000000bd2a400 id: 2972, updated_at: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 09:45:03 UTC +00:00, project_parent_id: 2964,
 
                                      **Project:0x0000000bd2a298 id: 2971**  updated_at: Wed, 19 Sep 2018 09:44:30 UTC +00:00, project_parent_id: 2966

Answer (score 0):

```
Project.unscoped.group("updated_at,project_parent_id,id")
                .select("project_parent_id, id, updated_at")
                .order(updated_at: :desc)
                .where("Date(projects.updated_at)>= ? AND Date(projects.updated_at)<= ?", start_date, end_date)
                .where("projects.last_modified_by = ? AND projects.project_parent_id != ?", user_id, nil).uniq
```

Comment: sorry. got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT ON` to get just the first row for each group from `project_parent_id` and the date from `updated_at`.

```
Project.unscoped
  .group("DATE(updated_at), project_parent_id, id")
  .select("DISTINCT ON (project_parent_id, DATE(updated_at)) project_parent_id, id, updated_at")
  .order(updated_at: :desc)
  .where('Date(projects.updated_at)>=? and Date(projects.updated_at)<=? and projects.last_modified_by=? and projects.project_parent_id is not ?', start_date, end_date, user_id, nil)
```